# NodeJS - How to write frontend for backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js

EDIT: I edited the whole question to be more precise.

So I'm hitting my head against the wall with this:

**SERVER.JS**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
//const app = require('express')();
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
//Enable CORS
app.use(cors());

const polls = [
  {
   ... 
  }
];

//Enable CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/polls', (req, res) => {
  let result = {polls:polls.map(function(p){
    return {id: p.id, title: p.title};
  })};
  res.json(result);
});


app.get('/polls/:id', (req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id-1;
  res.json(polls[id]);
});
```

So why isn't the part app.use(express.static(...)) not working? I've tried something like this:

**CONTROLLE.JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
  console.log("hello");


  var polls = function() {
    $http.get('/polls').then(function(response) {
      $scope.result = response;
    });
  };
}]);
```

But I can't even get the console.log("hello") out. Any help? I would appreciate if someone would tell me how to do this without writing the "app.use(express.static...)" in the server.js. Or is it even possible to get the result-map out without adding the express.static (or anything else to the server.js)?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean map from something? What do you want to map? What do you want to map it to?

Comment: use node as an api, request the data from a url and use it on the front end, which can be angularjs or any front end technology, or use pug or jade engine in the nodejs itself

Comment: Send an XHR GET request from your frontend to '/thingy'

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Do you want a frontend to a backend API or do everything server-side?

Comment: H.Vu, could you elaborate on what you want to achieve? Do you want to create and return a JSON on server side?

Comment: Hi!
So the problem is that I don't know how to link my html file to the server.js-file.

Answer (score 0):

You can either go for stand alone independent front end web app or Mobile app which will consume your `/thingy` API like using Javascript you can us $http to call the API and get data and display on web page. This can be develop using Angularjs or pure Javascript and HTML

> OR

You can use template engines like [Pug(Jade)](https://pugjs.org/). Using this kind of template you can render Pug file using `res.render(index.pug, {data: result})` and in `index.pug` file you can access whatever data you passed from render function.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi and thanks! So I'm going to use javascript and HTML. How can I get the information of the map from the server.js to my javascript and/or HTML file? Now my server.js only prints json to my web page.

Comment: You haven't add HTML code to your edit, please paste your html code too, where you have attached angular app directive to html